# Error: error getting chaincode bytes: failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim/internal

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to package my chaincode in hyperledger fabric 2.2 however getting error as `Error: error getting chaincode bytes: failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim/internal` but when same chaincode I used in hyperledger fabric 1.4.6 its work fine and I can install and init chaincode successfully.
Please help me to find the issue or where I am getting wrong advise me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The 1.4 version of the chaincode and the 2.x version of the chaincode have different go versions, and some of the usage methods are different.

Comment: 2.x version operates based on go vendor and utilizes [`fabric-chaincode-go`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go). If you simply used fabric shims for import, modify them in chaincode. In latest fabric is developing using [`fabric-contract-api-go`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go).

Comment: You can easily compare at [`fabric-samples`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples). Compare how the `chaincode/fabcar` in the link above is used on the 1.4 branch and the master branch.

Comment: For more detailed answers, please attach your code.
That way I can write answer. The information you gave me is not enough.

Comment: Hi @myeongkilkim thanks for your help I got it  though your comments Its clear my thought.